# Jquery If/Else always evaluating to true

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Having a little trouble with an if/else seems to be always true

```
<a id="test" class="art-bottom detailvid" href="/redblank" target="_blank">Check-In Video</a>

$(document).ready(function() {      
    if ($('a[href="/blank"]')) {
       $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kcn/MGE/KcnMGEd9i.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
    } else {
      $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/McL/L7p/McLL7pkKi.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
    }    
});
```

So, no matter what I make `href` it still show the first photo.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for the length of returned object in if statement. you should also change the value of attr href used in if statement to "/redblank":

```
if ($('a[href="/redblank"]').length) {
   $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kcn/MGE/KcnMGEd9i.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
} else {
  $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/McL/L7p/McLL7pkKi.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
}
```

**### Demo**

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake. Instead of testing the presence of the element, you need to test the `length`, like so:

```
if ($('a[href="/blank"]').length) {...}
```

There are two concepts you need to be familiar with in order to understand why this works.

The first is how a jQuery wrapped set works. `$('a')`, for example:

When you select an element with jQuery, even if the element doesn't exist on the page, jQuery still creates the "container" (a pseudo-array) but it  will be empty. This can be demonstrated by the following:

- Open the console of your browser and type in `var test = $('.doesNotExist')`
- Hit enter.
- On the next line log out that variable by typing `test` and hitting enter again.

You will see:

```
[]
```

This is an empty jQuery wrapped set. The set exists but is empty. You can call the `.length` method on this pseudo-array just as you would on a regular array, and in this case, you will get `0`.

```
test.length // returns 0
```

The second concept to understand is how *truthy* and *falsy* values work in `if` statements:

If you put a zero (`0`) or a `null` or an empty string (`""`) into an `if` statement, the `if` statement will reduce it down to a false. But if you put a regular string (`"hello"`) or a number (`22`) or even an empty array (`[]`), the `if` statement will evaluate it to true.

- `if(undefined){...}` will evaluate to false
- `if(""){...}` will evaluate to false
- `if(2){...}` will evaluate to true
- `if("hiya"){...}` will evaluate to true
- `if([]){...}` will evaluate to true

As you can see, if you place an empty jQuery set (`[]`) into an `if` statement, it is considered to be a *truthy* value and your `if` block will run.

The solution is to test the length of the jQuery set, which if empty, will result in zero (`0`), which is a *falsy* value.

Comment: Thank you for the info. When length is zero when using  if statement - will this get skipped not rendering at all?

Comment: Correct. The 0 (zero) will translate to a `false` and cause the `if` block to be skipped.

Comment: And we get the zero because the statement `$('a[href="/blank"]').length` evaluates to a zero, which evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition like this

```
if ($('a').attr('href') == "/blank") {
   $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kcn/MGE/KcnMGEd9i.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
} else {
  $( "a" ).append( '<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/McL/L7p/McLL7pkKi.png" height="28px" width="28px">' );
}
```